# jQuery star rating plugin not working in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-events

I have tried to integrate jQuery star rating plugin called jQuery master in to my PHP application, but its not working. Can anyone help me? Below is my code:

```
{literal}

<!-- include CSS & JS files -->
<!-- CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jRatingmaster/jquery/jRating.jquery.css" media="screen" />
<!-- jQuery files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo CONST_SITE_ADDRESS;?>jRatingmaster/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo CONST_SITE_ADDRESS;?>jRatingmaster/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

       // alert('hi'); 
      // get the clicked rate !
      $(".basic").jRating({
        
        onClick : function(element,rate) {
         alert(rate);
        }
      });
});
</script>

{/literal}


<div class="exemple">
  
  <div class="basic" data-average="8" data-id="2"></div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Look into the code of html page, do you have a normal URL for jquery and next script? check browser's console for messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, run your page in Mozilla FireFox, and check if any javascript/CSS file is not getting included.

In the `Net` tab, it shows a `404` with red color.

In the code, `<?php echo CONST_SITE_ADDRESS;?>` will not work in `Smarty` as it is being seen from your code.

From your PHP file, assign this to some variable display it in template.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo CONST_SITE_ADDRESS;?>jRatingmaster/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo CONST_SITE_ADDRESS;?>jRatingmaster/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>
```

So, the corrected code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$YOUR_PATH}jRatingmaster/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$YOUR_PATH}jRatingmaster/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: yea..its worked...i corrected code as 

<script type="text/javascript" src="{/literal}{$smarty.const.CONST_SITE_ADDRESS}{literal}jRatingmaster/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{/literal}{$smarty.const.CONST_SITE_ADDRESS}{literal}jRatingmaster/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>

Comment: but i want star rating..its not displaying star..only horizondal bar..can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

As per the [**documentation**](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/) specified, there is no `onclick` handler in **jrating** plugin.

Your code should be like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".basic").jRating();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: but i want star rating..its not displaying star..only horizondal bar..can u help me ?

Comment: @lara, Have you seen the documentation page?

Comment: I have specified the documentation link in my answer. Again here http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/

Comment: yea..this one i have tried..but am getting horizondal yellow bar instead of star...i don't understand why?

Comment: @lara, Star image may not be loaded properly. Can you check your console for this.

Comment: download the icon from the jrating site and move it in your web project images folder and add that in css file.